# Data not updated from HTML Table to Excel

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping

I have the following error, the data is updated in the webpage, but it is not in Excel. I use Application.OnTime to refresh the webpage.

Below are the code

```
Sub RefreshAction()
Dim htm As Object
Dim Tr As Object
Dim Td As Object
Dim Tab1 As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim Colstart As Long
Dim HTML As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim ss As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
URL = "http://register.um.edu.my/kok_kosong_bi.asp"
Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile") 'Create HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp") 'Get the WebPage Content
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    HTML.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
End With

Colstart = 1
j = 1
i = Colstart
n = 0

'Loop Through website tables
For Each Tab1 In HTML.getElementsByTagName("table")
    With HTML.getElementsByTagName("table")(n)
        For Each Tr In .Rows
            For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                Sheet1.Cells(j, i) = Td.innerText
                i = i + 1
            Next Td
            i = Colstart
            j = j + 1
        Next Tr
    End With
    n = n + 1
    i = Colstart
    j = j + 1
Next Tab1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Debug.Print Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RefreshAction", Schedule = True
End Sub
```

[The snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYmrd.png)

As per the snapshot, the website has 7 row, but excel only capture 5 row only. I have tried every possible way, still can't find the reason. I am expecting to clear the web cache, but I could not find the reference to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers change on the website. It was 6 rows when I first looked, then 5, and then later 6 again.

Your code is fine, but you need `Schedule:=True` rather than `Schedule = True` (typo?), and do you really need to loop all tables? You could also `Dim HTML As Object`.

I think the website is rather sketchy, to be honest, if exhibiting this type of inconsistency in results.

An easy way to get all rows, at any given time, is to simply copy paste the entire table as shown below. You can link that in with your refresh code.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://register.um.edu.my/kok_kosong_bi.asp", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Cells.ClearFormats
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText html.getElementsByTagName("table")(3).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: `WriteTxtFile` is a function? Which reference does it used? I understand the idea of it. Way better than mine :)

Comment: Oops. I left my debugging code line in there. That writes response html out for me to verify things visually.

Comment: Your code is fine but you need Schedule:=True    rather than Schedule = True (typo?) and do you really need to loop all tables? You could also  Dim HTML As Object